# Programming a game of pig/formatting if/while statements

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer

I am trying to code a simple game of "pig" where the rules are this: Two players roll dice to make it to 100. Player one starts and can roll as many times as they wish, or stop at any time and pass to the next player. If player one rolls a one, their totals for that round are 0 and the next players turn starts. If player one rolls anything other than a one, they can pass and add that round's totals to their final, or continue to roll and build up that round's total, then pass. Player two then chooses to roll and can continue or stop, and must stop if they roll a 1 and lose that round's totals. The first player to 100 points wins.

```
import random


player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0

while player1_score!=100 and player2_score!=100:
    turn = 0
    if (turn%2) == 0:
        player1_turnscore = 0
        while player1_turnscore<100:
            rollornot = input("Player one, would you like to roll the dice or pass? Roll (R) or Pass (P) ")
            if rollornot == "R":
                dice_value1= random.randint(1,6)
                print("you rolled a",dice_value1)
                player1_turnscore +=dice_value1
                if dice_value1==1:
                    player1_turnscore = 0
                    print("You have lost all points you accumulated this turn. Your score is still",player1_score," Player 2 starts.")
                    turn+=1
                    break
            else:
                turn+=1
                player1_score+=player1_turnscore
                print("Your score after that round is",player1_score)
                break
            print("your current score this turn is",player1_turnscore)
    else:
        player2_turnscore = 0
        while player2_turnscore<100:
            rollornot2 = input("Player two, would you like to roll the dice or pass? Roll (R) or Pass (P) ")
            if rollornot2 == "R":
                dice_value2= random.randint(1,6)
                print("you rolled a",dice_value2)
                player2_turnscore +=dice_value2
                if dice_value2==1:
                    player2_turnscore = 0
                    print("You have lost all points you accumulated this turn. Your score is still",player2_score," Player 2 starts.")
                    turn+=1
                    break
            else:
                turn+=1
                player2_score+=player2_turnscore
                print("Your score after that round is",player2_score)
                break
            print("your current score this turn is",player2_turnscore)
```

Now I'm not sure how to switch to player 2 upon a player 1 pass or lose condition. I have the turn variable being added to every time so it should be 1 after player 1 gets done the first time, but it just replays the first rollornot

Link to the rules in case my explanation is horrible, which it probably is:
https://www.dicegamedepot.com/dice-n-games-blog/pig-dice-game-rules/

The 'if' statement at the top of the main 'while' statement checks what turn it is by checking for an even number, player 1 turn will always be even.

Comment: The loop `while player1_turnscore<100:` keeps rolling the die without asking the user if they want to roll again. it doesn't break out of the loop until they roll a `1` and lose all their points for the round.

Comment: That makes sense though i'm not clear on how to add that at the moment

Comment: You should ask the `rollornot` question inside that loop.

Comment: If I have a further question should I edit this post or post another? I'm further along and your help worked but I hit another wall

Comment: If it's closely related, edit the question.

Comment: It was the same program, I edited the question

Comment: I'll finish up for now, hope somebody comes with the answer soon

Comment: `turn = 0` should not be inside the loop, it should be before the loop. It sets the turn back to player 0 before each iteration. This is a common beginner mistake.

Comment: thanks for the help, I went ahead and posted the answer and the finished program for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had the turn=0 variable inside of the while loop, resetting it to 0 on each recursion. Then the if statement checks each time if turn is even or not, if it is even then it is player 1's turn, if not then player 2. I have posted my finished program here, which is a complete 2 human player game of pig.

```
import random


player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0
turn=0
winner=False

while player1_score<101 and player2_score<101 and winner==False:
    if turn%2==0:      #this checks whether the turn is an even-numbered integer. If it is even, it is player one's turn
        player1_turnscore = 0
        while player1_turnscore<101 and winner==False:
            print("Player 1, your overall score is",player1_score)
            rollornot = input("Player 1, Would you like to roll the dice or pass? Roll (R) or Pass (P) ")
            if rollornot == "R":
                dice_value1= random.randint(1,6)
                print("you rolled a",dice_value1)
                player1_turnscore +=dice_value1    #cumulative score per round
                if dice_value1==1:
                    player1_turnscore = 0
                    turn+=1
                    print("You have lost all points you accumulated this turn. Your score is still",player1_score,". Player 2 starts.")
                    break
                if (player1_turnscore+player1_score)>=100:
                    print("Congratulations, Player 1, you won!")
                    winner=True #this helps close the while loop
                    break
            else:
                turn+=1
                player1_score+=player1_turnscore
                print("Player 1, your overall score after that round is",player1_score)
                break
            print("your current score this turn is",player1_turnscore)
    else:   #when turn is not even
        player2_turnscore = 0
        while player2_turnscore<101 and winner==False:
            print("Player 2, your overall score is",player2_score)
            rollornot2 = input("Player 2, would you like to roll the dice or pass? Roll (R) or Pass (P) ")
            if rollornot2 == "R":
                dice_value2= random.randint(1,6)
                print("you rolled a",dice_value2)
                player2_turnscore +=dice_value2  #cumulative score per round
                if dice_value2==1:
                    player2_turnscore = 0
                    print("You have lost all points you accumulated this turn. Your score is still",player2_score,". Player 1 starts.")
                    turn+=1
                    break
                if (player2_turnscore+player2_score)>=100:
                    print("Congratulation, Player 2, you won!!")
                    winner=True
                    break
            else:
                turn+=1
                player2_score+=player2_turnscore
                print("Player 2, your overall score after that round is",player2_score)
                break
            print("your current score this turn is",player2_turnscore)
```